# Azure Mobile Services vs Own REST service

Tags: rest, azure, mobile

I'm writing a mobile application, and this mobile application will be talking to a server in Azure to get data, and possibly push some too.

Now, I always had it in mind that I was going to write a simple RESTful web service that was going to deal with all this, and host it on Azure in a website - however, I've since discovered their Mobile Services, and I'm not entirely sure I understand what it's for.

Looking at it, it seems that it's about extracting away the code running on the server from you, and what you push to it, is what you get back? So it wouldn't be much use for me, as my web service is going to be returning data dependant on logic etc. However the ability for the Mobile Services to deal with push notifications directly is nice (how hard is it to use Azure Websites to send push notifications through mobile services?)

However, I wonder if I'm missing something? I'd rather not have to go re-invent the wheel as such, is Mobile Services will do what I need, especially as I'll be using Xamarin and there is a nice component to talk to Mobile Services...

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am facing the same question: Should I use Azure Mobile Services or roll my own REST service. Below are some discoveries I have made so far.

With Azure Mobile Services there is a backend running a set of assemblies, which your code ultimately depends on. This is fine until you start using versions of other assemblies, which are not compatible with the versions Microsoft hosts. To me this is a major pain. This problem alone makes me question whether I want to use Azure Mobile Services. If you make your own REST service, I do not expect you to face these problems. [See this link for details.](http://bytepacker.blogspot.no/2014/09/how-to-solve-conflicts-between.html)

You should note that an Azure Mobile Services is tied to a single Azure region: If your Azure region fails, you need to manually migrate to another Azure region. This might not be a problem for your project. If you want to run in more than one region, I think it will be easier to roll your own REST service.

Regarding push notification, you could do that without using Mobile Service. See these links:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/jj927170.aspx
- http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/broadcast-push-notifications-to-millions-of-mobile-devices-using-windows-azure-notification-hubs

Auto-scaling is supported out-of-the-box in Azure Mobile Services. You would need to make your own scaling logic if you make your own REST service. You can scale VMs using Azure’s REST API, but it will be more work than using Mobile Services.

Authentication is supported in Azure Mobile Services. You would need to look into a separate framework to do this if you make your own REST service.

If you use Mobile Services you will probably create ASP.NET Web APIs through the Visual Studio wizards. There are examples and tutorials, which is great. However, even if you roll your own service, you could build on other frameworks. One example is [ServiceStack](https://servicestack.net/), which I would strongly consider if you want to make your own REST service. I think ServiceStack could also help with authentication.

If you use Mobile Services you will tie yourself stronger to Azure. By rolling your own REST service it will probably be easier to move to another infrastructure later.

Comment: That's a great answer. One thing I would say though, is that if you role the service into an azure website, that should autoscale with the standard website stuff. I tried out the mobile services and I came across a load of issues even getting something simple to run as it was looking at an invalid connection string that wasn't defined anywhere, either on Web config or on azure, so it's instantly put me off as I don't want to be fighting azure. So I may very well roll my own. Another advantage to rolling your own is custom urls, otherwise you have to use Azures own url structure, tying you

Comment: I'll mark as answer as it was a very useful answer to understand the pros and cons. Cheers